# Another split file in bash - based on difference between rows of column x

Tags: bash, csv, awk, split

Hello stackoverflow users!

Generally I would like to tune up script I am using, just to make it more insensitive to missing data.
My example data looks like this (tab delimited csv file with headers):

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
6   0   0
3   5.16551 12.1099
1   10.2288 19.4769
6   20.0249 30.6543
3   30.0499 40.382
1   59.9363 53.2281
2   74.9415 57.1477
2   89.9462 61.3308
6   119.855 64.0319
4   0   0
8   5.06819 46.8086
6   10.0511 60.1357
9   20.0363 71.679
6   30.0228 82.1852
6   59.8738 98.4446
3   74.871  100.648
1   89.9973 102.111
6   119.866 104.148
3   0   0
1   5.07248 51.9168
2   9.92203 77.3546
2   19.9233 93.0228
6   29.9373 98.7797
6   59.8709 100.518
6   74.7751 100.056
3   89.9363 99.5933
1   119.872 100
```

I use `awk` script found elsewhere, as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN { fn=0 }
NR==1 { next }
NR==2 { delim=$2 }
$2 == delim {
    f=sprintf("file_no%02d.txt",fn++);
    print "Creating " f
}

{ print $0 > f }'
```

Which gives me output I want - omit 1st line, find 2nd column and set delimiter - in this example it will be '0':

```
file_no00.txt
6   0   0
3   5.16551 12.1099
1   10.2288 19.4769
6   20.0249 30.6543
3   30.0499 40.382
1   59.9363 53.2281
2   74.9415 57.1477
2   89.9462 61.3308
6   119.855 64.0319

file_no01.txt
4   0   0
8   5.06819 46.8086
6   10.0511 60.1357
9   20.0363 71.679
6   30.0228 82.1852
6   59.8738 98.4446
3   74.871  100.648
1   89.9973 102.111
6   119.866 104.148

    file_no02.txt
3   0   0
1   5.07248 51.9168
2   9.92203 77.3546
2   19.9233 93.0228
6   29.9373 98.7797
6   59.8709 100.518
6   74.7751 100.056
3   89.9363 99.5933
1   119.872 100
```

To make the script more robust (imagine that rows with 0's are deleted) I would need to split file according to the subtracted value of rows 'n+1' and 'n' if this value is below 0 split file, so basically if `(value_row_n+1)-value_row_n < 0` then split file. Of course I would need also to maintain the file naming. Preferred way is `bash` with `awk` use. Any advices? Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: `if (n+1)-n < 0` will always return FALSE Can you try to explain your question little more.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for the comment, the statement 'if (n+1)-n < 0' for the 2nd column in the `big file` (first example) has 3 TRUE points, and I want to use it as split points

Comment: what's confusing here is that isn't `(n+1)-n == 1?` Is n and the other n different?

Comment: @konsolebox that is the point, I will edit the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is awk command that you can use:

```
cat file
ColA    ColB    ColC
3       5.16551 12.1099
1       10.2288 19.4769
6       20.0249 30.6543
3       30.0499 40.382
1       59.9363 53.2281
2       74.9415 57.1477
2       89.9462 61.3308
6       119.855 64.0319
8       5.06819 46.8086
6       10.0511 60.1357
9       20.0363 71.679
6       30.0228 82.1852
6       59.8738 98.4446
3       74.871  100.648
1       89.9973 102.111
6       119.866 104.148
1       5.07248 51.9168
2       9.92203 77.3546
2       19.9233 93.0228
6       29.9373 98.7797
6       59.8709 100.518
6       74.7751 100.056
3       89.9363 99.5933
1       119.872 100
awk 'NR == 1 {
  next
}
!p || $2 < p {
   f = sprintf("file_no%02d.txt",fn++);
   print "Creating " f
}
{
   p = $2;
   print $0 > f
}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest small modifications to your current script:

```
awk 'BEGIN { fn=0; f=sprintf("file_no%02d.txt",fn++); print "Creating " f }
NR==1 { next }
NR==2 { delim=$2 }
$2 - delim < 0 {
    f=sprintf("file_no%02d.txt",fn++);
    print "Creating " f
}

{ print $0 > f; delim = $2 }' infile
```

First, create the first file name just before starting the processing.

Second, in last condition save the value of current line to compare with the value of next line.

Third, instead the comparison with zero, do the substraction between previous value and current one to check if result is less than zero.

It yields:

```
==> file_no00.txt <==
6   0   0
3   5.16551 12.1099
1   10.2288 19.4769
6   20.0249 30.6543
3   30.0499 40.382
1   59.9363 53.2281
2   74.9415 57.1477
2   89.9462 61.3308
6   119.855 64.0319

==> file_no01.txt <==
4   0   0
8   5.06819 46.8086
6   10.0511 60.1357
9   20.0363 71.679
6   30.0228 82.1852
6   59.8738 98.4446
3   74.871  100.648
1   89.9973 102.111
6   119.866 104.148

==> file_no02.txt <==
3   0   0
1   5.07248 51.9168
2   9.92203 77.3546
2   19.9233 93.0228
6   29.9373 98.7797
6   59.8709 100.518
6   74.7751 100.056
3   89.9363 99.5933
1   119.872 100
```